# Converting SQL query and creating an association between 2 tables in the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have just 2 models : `item` and `order`, I know use these models like that :

```
Item.count(:all)
Order.count(:all)
```

But I would like to do this query : (joining 2 tables but just for the conditions)

```
SELECT count(i.id)
FROM somethingitem as i, somethingorder as o
WHERE i.uid = o.uid_order
AND o.cancelled = 0
AND o.cashier = 1
AND o.seller = 0;
```

or with INNER JOIN :

```
SELECT count(i.id)
FROM somethingitem as i
INNER JOIN somethingorder as o
WHERE i.uid = o.uid_order
AND o.cancelled = 0
AND o.cashier = 1
AND o.seller = 0;
```

Models :

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
self.table_name = "somethingitem"
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
self.table_name = "somethingorder"
end
```

My tables don't have any index or key. (no primary neither foreign)

Thank you.

**Edit :** For the moment, I use Item.count_by_sql("My query") and it works.

**Edit 2 :** Ok, To use Activerecord into a existing db, I have to create an association between my 2 tables but just in the rails model, not in my db ! belongs_to , has _many or has_one... My field names hasn't rails standard.

`Order can have many items.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails makes this easy if you setup the correct associations in your models.  As you noted, your primary/foreign keys aren't following the ActiveRecord convention, so you'll need to give the association a bit more information:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order, foreign_key: 'uid', primary_key: 'uid_order'
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items, foreign_key: 'uid', primary_key: 'uid_order'
end
```

You can now do this:

```
Item.joins(:order).where(orders: {cancelled: 0, cashier: 1, seller: 0}).count
```

You can make this query cleaner if you put the order scope in the Order class (where it more naturally belongs anyhow):

```
class Order
  def self.cashier
    where(cashier: 1, seller: 0)
  end

  def self.non_cancelled
    where(cancelled: 0)
  end
end
```

And now you can do the same query like this:

```
Item.joins(:order).merge(Order.non_cancelled.cashier).count
```

Comment: The query seems good but in my class, I have `self.table_name = "somethingorder"` and `self.table_name = "somethingitem"` and `Unknown column 'order.cancelled' in 'where clause': `  my table is `somethingorder` not `order`.

Comment: Yes, it's difficult but my db has > 4 millions rows, I'm unable to make a new structure. And I would like that my rails app will work when I'll migrate.

Comment: `Item.joins(:order).where("somethingorder" => {cancelled: 0, cashier: 1, seller: 0}).count` works, but why the where clause doesn't get the "table_name" of `:receipt` ...

Comment: @Alexis_user The `where` clause arguments need to follow the SQL syntax (including the actual table name in your case) to permit more creative queries that ActiveRecord would have a hard time discerning.  You could put this logic as a scope/class-method in Order, and merge that method into the query if you want to avoid this (updated to demonstrate this).  Hopefully, ActiveRecord will be smart enough to handle this on its own one day...

Comment: Thank you very much PinnyM, I'll try your solution. But I think that I found another solution `Item.joins(:order).where(Order.table_name: {cancelled: 0, cashier: 1, seller: 0}).count`. Order.table_name will return always the name of the table even if I don't put ``self.table_name ="real_name"` into the Order class.   But your solution seems really better !!